# Why did they find Eowyn so far away from Theoden

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-return-of-the-king

In the *Return of the King* movie, the last shot of Eowyn (before the Rohirrim find her) has her crying over Theoden's body. A few shots after that, the Rohirrim find her. But she isn't lying anywhere near Theoden.

Is this a simple filming goof? Or did they not include something in the movie that was in the books, like she wandered around the battlefield to help wounded soldiers?

Answer (score 17):

In the extended edition of the film a section of restored content showed the Orc general Gothmog attempted to kill Eowyn.

In this sequence Eowyn crawled a decent distance away from Theoden attempting to grab a sword until Aragorn (Big Damn Hero he is) dropped by and killed Gothmog.

Comment: Sod it ain't that great an answer, i was expecting to get sniped by some guy with a clip

Comment: But the two scenes actually happens in the opposite order in the extended edition. First she crawls away from Gothmog THEN she talks to Theoden dying. So the last scene before Eomer find her is still her next to Theoden. What I also found very odd is that we never see her pass out, I really feel that some scene is missing.

Answer (score 7):

In the book, Théoden is found shortly before his death, so this problem is side-stepped:

> 'Hail, King of the Mark!' [Théoden] said. 'Ride now to victory! Bid Éowyn farewell!' And so he died, and knew not that Éowyn lay near him. And those who stood by wept, crying: 'Théoden King! Théoden King!'
>
> *[...]*
>
> Yet [Éomer] himself wept as he spoke. 'Let his knights remain here,' he said; 'and bear his body in honour from the field, lest the battle ride over it! Yea, and all these other of the king's men that lie here.' And he looked at the slain, recalling their names. Then suddenly he beheld his sister Éowyn as she lay, and he knew her.
>
> <sup>*Return of the King* Book V Chapter 6: "The Battle of the Pelennor Fields"</sup>

So this is purely a movie invention. Unfortunately I can't find this scene in the script, so we can only speculate.

The most plausible explanation is that Théoden was moved, but Éowyn left behind. Théoden was a king, after all, so the priority would have been to remove his body from the battlefield. If someone did that without recognizing Éowyn (which seems plausible, since nobody was expecting her to be there), she most likely would have been left behind.

Comment: That sounds like an awful tactical decision, diverting a bunch of knights to safeguard one dead person... It may matter to morale, but who cares about morale if you get defeated for lack of soldiers? +1 anyway, since I can't blame you for Eomer's lack of tactical acumen :)

Comment: @DVK Presumably this would be after the battle, when that's a slightly less-relevant concern

Comment: no full text right now so can't check, but my vague memory is this was still before battle was finished. " lest the battle ride over it! " seems to confirm that?

Comment: @DVK Oh, you meant the book; sorry, thought you meant the movie. Yes,  that's probably a bit silly. But, I mean; he's the King

Comment: I'm mildly hurt :) When have i EVER given the impression that I respect film "canon" anywhere as much as real book canon, including when it comes to Tolkien? :))

Comment: @DVK I submit myself for scorn and ridicule. In my defense, I haven't had my coffee yet

Comment: That definitely is a valid defense... well, it OUGHT to be.